# jquery stopPropogation() not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

here is my html :

```
<span class="checkbox checked replacement" tabindex="0">
   <span class="check-knob"></span>
   <input type="checkbox" name="data[InfoPagesClient][3][info_page_id]" value="25"                                                                      checked="checked" class="">
</span>
<label for="InfoPagesClient3InfoPageId" class="label">asdasd</label>
```

now I want to show hide this pencil box on checkbox click event..

javascript :

```
$("p.checkbox-group span.checkbox").on('click', function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('checked')) {
        $(imgId).hide();
    } else {
        console.log('aaaaaaaaaaa');
        $(imgId).show();
    }
});

$("label.label").on('click', function(e) {
    if ($(this).siblings('span.checkbox').hasClass('checked')) {
        $(imgId).hide();
    } else {
        $(imgId).show();
    }
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
```

clikcing on label it is going to span click event and prints console value... I tried using e.stopPropogation() and stopImmediatePropogation().. but ti is not working..

any idea ??

Answer (score 0):

e.stopPropogation() or e.stopImmediatePropogation() will prevent the event from bubbling up, but will not stop the event immediately.

You can use e.preventDefault() along with e.stopPropogation(). e.preventDefault() will prevent the default event from occurring. You can check with the following change in your code.

```
$("p.checkbox-group span.checkbox").on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    if($(this).hasClass('checked')) {
        $(imgId).hide();
    } else {
        console.log('aaaaaaaaaaa');
        $(imgId).show();
    }
});

$("label.label").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    if ($(this).siblings('span.checkbox').hasClass('checked')) {
        $(imgId).hide();
    } else {
        $(imgId).show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `label` with `for`, browser will automatically click the associated control which triggers the "click" event. That is another event triggered later, in your case when you use `e.stopImmediatePropagation();`, **it just stops the current "click" event** and has no effect on the event of the associated control **fired after that**

To fix your issue, try removing `for`

Use this:

```
<label class="label">asdasd</label>
```

Instead of:

```
<label for="InfoPagesClient3InfoPageId" class="label">asdasd</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add the `id` attribute to your checkbox, then the label will work. Then you can simplify your code as follows:

```js
$(function () {
    $("p.checkbox-group input[type=checkbox]").on('change', function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            $(this).parent().addClass('checked').siblings('a.edit-content').hide();
        } else {
            $(this).parent().removeClass('checked').siblings('a.edit-content').show();
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gFXcm/2/

Answer (score 0):

mmmh, isn't it a feature instead of a bug ? shouldn't the click on the label trigger the same action as the click on the "checkbox" ? That's precisely why the `for` attribute is used I guess.